# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value While unwrapping SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am getting the following error at the mentioned line of code

[image]

[image]

Even though the debugger shows that bg has been assigned a value, that it fetches from .sks file. (GameScene.sks file contains an object named as bg)
Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

-> -> **EDIT**
Whilst no thanks to the community here thats full of people who'd just try to be uncanningly witty and gods of humor, i managed to figure it out myself. So for a future reference if someone else falls in the same situation, i am sharing the code that was the reason for the problematic error.

[image]

Comment: show where you name the node in the sks, just to be sure

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time the debugger will show a value for `bg` that was previously there on the stack (garbage in the memory).

It will never write something to `bg` because the program crashes while evaluating the value for the variable so you are just seeing garbage.

The error you can see clearly means there is no node named `bg`.

Comment: I would add a fix in your code by saying `if let bg = childNodeWithName(“bg”) as? SKSpriteNode { // Do something with bg }`. This if statement is true when bg is a non-nil value of type SKSpriteNode. If it doesn’t evaluate as true chances are there is no child node of name “bg” and/or it it’s of type `SKSpriteNode`